# phpspec - specify that arguments should be passed to mock object

Tags: php, phpspec

I'm new to [PHPSpec](http://www.phpspec.net/) and [BDD/TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) in general.

Given the following code:

```
interface Checker
{
    public function execute(array $args = array());
}

class Check
{
    public $checker;

    public $params = array();

    public function doCheck()
    {
    }
}
```

**I'd like to specify that the Check class needs to pass it's arguments to the Checker, but I'm unsure how to do so.**

My Spec:

```
class CheckSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{    
    function it_should_pass_params_to_checker_on_execute(\Checker $checker)
    {
        $checker->execute()->willReturn(true);
        $this->checker = $checker;
        $this->params = array(1,2);
        $this->doCheck();
        $checker->execute(array(1,2))->shouldHaveBeenCalled();
    }
}
```

When I run the spec, *before* the implementation in Checker Class I get:

```
9  - it should pass params to checker on execute
  no calls been made that match:
    Double\Checker\P1->execute(exact([1, 2]))
  but expected at least one.
```

Once I implement:

```
class Check
{
    public $checker;

    public $params = array();

    public function doCheck()
    {
        $this->checker->execute($this->params);
    }
}
```

I get:

```
9  - it should pass params to checker on execute
  method call:
    - execute([1, 2])
  on Double\Checker\P1 was not expected, expected calls were:
    - execute()
```

What gives?  As far as I can tell, I implemented as specified.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
class CheckSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{    
    function it_should_pass_params_to_checker_on_execute(\Checker $checker)
    {
        // I should've created my mock with the expected parameters
        $checker->execute(array(1,2))->willReturn(true);
        // Like so ------>^^^^^^^^^^^      
        $this->checker = $checker;
        $this->params = array(1,2);
        $this->doCheck();
        $checker->execute(array(1,2))->shouldHaveBeenCalled();
    }
}
```